# Can't login to Firebase on StackBlitz

Tags: stackblitz

The Firebase integration is not working, I give StackBlitz access to my personal Google account, it loads, and it nothing happens, it still says that I have not yet connected my Google account to StackBlitz.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had Firebase setup but didn't create a project yet, once I did that it worked perfectly.